# UTC datetime range

Tags: mongodb, date, time, range, utc

I am trying to understand how UTC datetime is represented and what is the maximum and minimum range. Mongodb uses UTC datetime to represent dates.

For example: In MySQL, datetime takes 8 bytes and the ranges are :

1000-01-01 00:00:00:000000 to 9999-12-31 23:59:59:999999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#date) on the BSON Date data type that's used to represent datetimes:

> BSON Date is a 64-bit integer that represents the number of
>   milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970). This results in a
>   representable date range of about 290 million years into the past and
>   future.